# Is there any known way to send strings or data from a html page to a c++ application?

Tags: javascript, html, c++, widget, webserver

I am new to this area and just wanted to know if this sort of thing is possible. I can't seem to find much only about it. The only thing I could think of was a javascript backend that communicates to a C++ application.

I looked at Qwidget toolkits for C++, yet I could not find any example of this online.

**Ultimately I'm trying to take a html page (served using node.JS) and to have a button, that when clicked, sends a string of data to a c++ application.**

I'm not sure how I'd implement POST or GET requests into this and if using a javascript backend is the way to go.

If anyone has come across this sort of method before, and could point me in the right direction, or even to a useful resource or example I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: It sounds like you have a form of some kind. There's not really enough information in your question to help you. What string of data are you wishing to send? Why do you need to send it?

Comment: Since you are already using nodeJS to serve the html, you can add an POST route that will receive the data and then either spawn the C++ program with exec/spawn (and pass the data as string) or use IPC to communicate with the app - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914128/ipc-node-js-server-communication-with-simple-c-code

Comment: @Goran.it Thanks. I'll give it a go

Comment: @Goran.it I've been looking at the example you sent with nodejs to C. Have you ever managed to get that to work? I try and run his example with the edits but have no luck. Ideally I'd like to put his javascript code into a function that is called by the html button and capable of outputting into terminal. Nothing happens tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **cpprest**. Just create http server on localhost and send **POST**, **GET** or **OPTIONS** requests. **It will take up less than one percent of the CPU.**

Example:

**httpserver.h**

```
#ifndef HTTPSERVER_H
#define HTTPSERVER_H

#include <cpprest/producerconsumerstream.h>
#include <cpprest/http_listener.h>
#include <cpprest/json.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <Assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")

using namespace std;
using namespace web;
using namespace http;
using namespace utility;
using namespace concurrency;
using namespace http::experimental::listener;

class HttpServer : public http_listener
{

public:
    HttpServer();
    ~HttpServer();

    //http request
private:
    void HandleGet(http_request request);
    void HandlePost(http_request request);
    void HandleOptions(http_request request);

    json::value ProcessRequest(json::value task);

private:
    //user info
    wstring data;
};


#endif
```

**httpserver.cpp**

```
#include "HttpServer.h"

HttpServer::HttpServer()
    : http_listener(L"http://localhost:9999"s)
{
    data= L"";

    //setting up the server
    this->support(methods::GET, bind(&HttpServer::HandleGet, this, placeholders::_1));
    this->support(methods::POST, bind(&HttpServer::HandlePost, this, placeholders::_1));
    this->support(methods::OPTIONS, bind(&HttpServer::HandleOptions, this, placeholders::_1));

}

HttpServer::~HttpServer()
{this->close();}

void HttpServer::HandleGet(http_request request)
{
    json::value jsonResponse(L"Get response from C++");
    http_response response(status_codes::OK);
    response.headers().add(U("Access-Control-Allow-Origin"), U("*"));
    response.set_body(jsonResponse);
    request.reply(response);
}

void HttpServer::HandlePost(http_request request)
{
    json::value jsonResponse;
    request.extract_json().then([&jsonResponse, this, &request](pplx::task<json::value> task)
    {
        jsonResponse = this->ProcessRequest(task.get());
    }).wait();

    //write status into http response
    http_response response(status_codes::OK);

    //if you need to add CORS into headers
    response.headers().add(U("Access-Control-Allow-Origin"), U("*"));
    response.set_body(jsonResponse);
    request.reply(response);
}

void HttpServer::HandleOptions(http_request request)
{
    http_response response(status_codes::OK);
    response.headers().add(U("Allow"), U("GET, POST, OPTIONS"));
    response.headers().add(U("Access-Control-Allow-Origin"), U("*"));
    response.headers().add(U("Access-Control-Allow-Methods"), U("GET, POST, OPTIONS"));
    response.headers().add(U("Access-Control-Allow-Headers"), U("Content-Type"));
    request.reply(response);

    return;
}

json::value HttpServer::ProcessRequest(json::value task)
{
        for (auto iterator = task.as_object().cbegin(); iterator != task.as_object().cend(); ++iterator)
        {
            const wstring& key = iterator->first;
            const json::value& value = iterator->second;

            if (key == L"data")
            {
                data = value.as_string();
                continue;
            }

            //if you need to send response
            response[L"response"] = json::value::boolean(true);
        }

    return response;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ::ShowWindow(::GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);

    unique_ptr<HttpServer> webServer = make_unique<HttpServer>();
    //listen 9999 port
    webServer->open().wait();

    while(true)
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));  //Simulate some work by sleeping

    return 0;
}
```

On the client side:

```
function requestREST(request/*json data*/,onSuccess/*callback with json response*/) {    
    $.ajax({     
        type: "POST",
        url: "...",
        data: JSON.stringify(request),
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (response) {
            onSuccess(response);
        },
        timeout:3000,
        statusCode: {
            400: function (response) {
                alert('Not working!');
            },
            0: function (response) {
                alert('Not working!');
            }              
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, this is extremely useful. Do I specify my PORT number or page's IP in the "main.CPP"?

Comment: This code works like a http server. You need to make http request on the `localhost:9999`. 
Via js you need to make simple client request (GET, POST, OPTIONS).

Comment: When using CPPREST and other libraries, do you need to download the headerfiles for them? 

For example the line "#include <cpprest/producerconsumerstream.h>" runs errors; I'd imagine c++ requires additional installs?

I'm new to the language sorry

Comment: @Alvydas Juodikis CPPREST is not included in STD. Read more about it in book "C++ from the ground up" of Herbert Schildt

Comment: Thanks @bogdyname; I found that I needed to install the package for CPPREST. The only package I can't seem to find online is for iphlpapi . Can't find the install instructions for linux

Comment: @Alvydas Juodikis, check it out https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/How-to-build-for-Linux

Comment: That link was what I used to install my package for cpprest however it was still missing the "iphlpapi" library. I'm doing this on eclipse so maybe that's the issue? Also the code you sent, does it belong to an online example that I could read into?

Comment: @Alvydas Juodikis, try to remove this lines on Linux `#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")` and `#include <iphlpapi.h>`